# Why the Collection Cell doesn't show on the collectionView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to IOS , and I want to implement the album by `collectionView` in IOS.

I create the `View`(name:**AITCameraCollectionBrowser.xib**) like the following picture.

[image]

and create the another `AITPhotoCell.xib file` like the following picture.

[image]

I want the `cell` show on the `collectionView`.

But both the `button` and `collectionView` in the `AITCameraCollectionBrowser` doesn't show.

And I don't know why the View doesn't show anything ?

The following code is in `viewDidLoad` for `AITCameraCollectionBrowser.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [self.collectionview registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    self.collectionview.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionview.delegate = self;

    [self.collectionview addSubview:_collectionview];


    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"AITPhotoCell" bundle:nil];

    [self.collectionview registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:[AITPhotoCell reuseIdentifier]];
}
```

Why the `button` and `collectionView` in the `AITCameraCollectionBrowser` doesn't show.

Do I lack for something in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: If you are a beginner, may I ask why are you using xib files and complicate things even more.

Comment: I found some example , it use xib file to implement. it use `tableView` , and I want to change from `tableView` to `CollectionView`.

Comment: You need to implement several UICollectionViewDataSource methods, at  least collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: and collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:

Comment: Try this one, it's not outdated like the one you found. [Beginning UICollectionView In iOS 6: Part 1/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)

Answer (score 0):

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(75,75)];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
[self.collectionview setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
[self.collectionview registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"AITPhotoCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
```

Try This.. its Working.. :)